# How to approx values on decimal places using pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

Looking through the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-approx) it says that by default the `approx` method evaluate until 3 decimal places on a number, but when i compare this value it returns `False`

```
pytest.approx(6.495) == 6.49  # False
```

How can i check if a number is approx. to another within decimal places?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't say that the default is within three decimal places, it says it's within `1e-6` - or `0.000001`.

> By default, approx considers numbers within a relative tolerance of 1e-6 (i.e. one part in a million) of its expected value to be equal. This treatment would lead to surprising results if the expected value was 0.0, because nothing but 0.0 itself is relatively close to 0.0. To handle this case less surprisingly, approx also considers numbers within an absolute tolerance of 1e-12 of its expected value to be equal.

The `rel` argument can be used to change what's consider approximately the same value:

```
>>> pytest.approx(6.495, rel=1e-3) == 6.49
True
```

Comment: thank you, is there a way to add `1e-3` on all tests on i need to pass the parameter every time?

Comment: You can create your own function and wrap the call / decorate the function with a default value.